# How can I create a custom map in Google Maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to create a Google Maps application that has the map of my house. (bedroom, wash room, kitchen etc)

Using GPS, I will find my present location in my house and try to get the direction/walking-distance to my bedroom. (You could use Google's API to get the direction)

What I need to know is:

1. How can I add a custom map of my house?
2. To get the direction and walking-distance? You will have to provide your current geo-coordinates (where I am right now) and your destinations (kitchen) geo-coordinates, so will Google be able to find the walking-distance and direction from where I am to the next place I want to go (to the kitchen)?

Comment: I think that using an Overlay would serve this purpose, would it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using GPS, I will find my present location in my house and try to get the direction/walking-distance to my bedroom.

Considering that the error range of GPS (~30m diameter circle) might be bigger than the footprint of your house, this seems unlikely to work well.

> How can I add a custom map of my house?

You don't. You are welcome to create your own activity with its own images and such, but that will not have anything to do with Google Maps.

> To get the direction and walking-distance?

You will need to calculate that yourself.