# What APIs to use to have private google map with navigation in Android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, opengl-es, google-maps-api-2

Is it possible to create something like a private map i.e. with private POI, labels and regions marked-out (as overlays) using Google maps, such that this information is available only to users using my application ?

Is this something that can be done using Google maps tools, and exported as a reference to private map ?

*Note: I've come across [an unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536573/how-to-add-custom-pois-to-google-maps-navigation) in SO, which indicates that it is perhaps possible, but from the google maps online interface, it is not quite clear, as to how it can be achieved.*

Does this require a commercial arrangement with Google ? Does it matter if the app is an ad (AdMob, perhaps) supported free app ? What might I have to do (or sacrifice) to not have to enter into a commercial arrangement with google ?

While searching, I have come across something called 'Google Maps Javascript API'. Apart from this, there is an obviously the 'Google Maps Android API v2'. Does the need to use navigation mandate using the latter (native approach) ? I see that 'Google Maps Android API v2' mandates availability of OpenGL ES 2.0 support. My target user, are likely to have many devices without OpenGL ES 2.0 support, so does it mean that I can only use the web-based mechanism ?

*Note: In my searches I've come across [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109793/how-can-i-create-a-custom-map-in-google-maps?rq=1), which seems to indicate that private POI's / private Maps using Google-Maps is perhaps not possible. Since the answer is from a highly respected authority on Android programming, I am wondering, but seems to counter intuitive if something of this sort is not possible.*

Answer (score 0):

1.) You can create and utilize your "own map" by implementing the [UrlTileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/UrlTileProvider.html) abstract class. Set the map type to NONE, and then use your own tile "overlay". Some reference [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/tileoverlay#add) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#change_the_map_type)

Your "map" assuming it's a graphic file with your stuff drawn in there will be fetched by your abstract class implementation with some calculations. A good example of this is the I/0 2014 app. Check it out here:

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/SVGTileProvider.java